# Variable Not Defined error in VBA for CurrentDb function for access DB

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am using currentDb method to get instance of database in VBA excel macro. I have added reference as well but CurrentDb method is giving error "Variable Not Defined"

Below is code

```
Dim Db As DAO.Database

Db = CurrentDb
```

Could you please help me on this

Comment: Added reference DAO 3.6 object library

Comment: `CurrentDb` is an Access method, so it's not going to work by itself in Excel VBA. Maybe if you posted more code someone might have a suggestion. With only two lines not much to go on.

Answer (score 4):

`CurrentDb` is an Access-specific global variable which is not defined in Excel.

You need to open a database instead:

```
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Set Db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Fred\Databases\Foo.mdb")
```

`OpenDatabase` is a member of the global object `DBEngine` from the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library (which I assume you have referenced because your code has the `DAO.Database` type).